# Unable to verify JobPosting in SDTT

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

Get frustrated with Schema.org’s [`JobPosting`](http://schema.org/JobPosting). I found Google Structured Data Testing Tool said:

> 100000 (The attribute baseSalary.itemtype has an invalid value.)

I have tried using this inside or outside of `JobPosting` as follows:

```json
 "@type":"MonetaryAmount",
     "EmployeeRole":{                       
    "baseSalary": "100000"                         
        }
```

However, I found more than one problem.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",  
  "@type": "JobPosting",  


    "baseSalary":"100000",


        "datePosted":"2017-06-18T15:14:57+00:00",
        "validThrough":"2017-12-31T00:00:00+00:00",
        "title":"Sales And Marketing Manager",
        "description":"Responsible for Corporate and Travel Agent Room Sales for the hotel",
        "educationRequirements":"S-1 Management",//educationRequirements
        "employmentType":"Kontrak 1 Tahun",//employmentType
        "experienceRequirements":"100 Tahun",//experienceRequirements
        "industry":"Perpajakan Daerah Sumedang",//industry
        "qualifications":"Single, Fresh Graduates dan suka ternak bebek",//qualifications
        "responsibilities":"Tukang mbersihin kadang embek",//responsibilities
        "skills":"Bisa menjahit, ngetik 40 jari",//skills
        "workHours":"Jam 10 s/d 70",//workHours
        "hiringOrganization":{
        "@type":"Organization",
            "name":"Equity Jimbaran Resort And Villa",
            "sameAs":"http://equityhoteljimbaran.com",
            "url":"http://equityhoteljimbaran.com"
            },
                    "jobLocation":{
                    "@type":"Place",
                        "address":{
                            "@type":"PostalAddress",
                                "addressRegion":"Bali",
                                "addressCountry":"ID",
                                "streetAddress":"Jl.Muara 3, KM.18, Blok4, RT04/05, Tanjung Perak",//streetAddress
                                "addressLocality":"Jimbaran",//addressLocality
                                "postalCode":"56161"//postalCode
                                }
                            }                    
        }      
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long distance, finally, I find the solution:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",  
  "@type": "JobPosting",  

      "baseSalary":{
      "@type":"MonetaryAmount",
          "value":"100000",
          "currency":"USD"
          },

        "datePosted":"2017-06-18T15:14:57+00:00",
        "validThrough":"2017-12-31T00:00:00+00:00",
        "title":"Sales And Marketing Manager",
        "description":"Responsible for Corporate and Travel Agent Room Sales for the hotel",
        "educationRequirements":"S-1 Management",//educationRequirements
        "employmentType":"Kontrak 1 Tahun",//employmentType
        "experienceRequirements":"100 Tahun",//experienceRequirements
        "industry":"Perpajakan Daerah Sumedang",//industry
        "qualifications":"Single, Fresh Graduates dan suka ternak bebek",//qualifications
        "responsibilities":"Tukang mbersihin kadang embek",//responsibilities
        "skills":"Bisa menjahit, ngetik 40 jari",//skills
        "workHours":"Jam 10 s/d 70",//workHours
        "hiringOrganization":{
        "@type":"Organization",
            "name":"Equity Jimbaran Resort And Villa",
            "sameAs":"http://equityhoteljimbaran.com",
            "url":"http://equityhoteljimbaran.com"
            },
                    "jobLocation":{
                    "@type":"Place",
                        "address":{
                            "@type":"PostalAddress",
                                "addressRegion":"Bali",
                                "addressCountry":"ID",
                                "streetAddress":"Jl.Muara 3, KM.18, Blok4, RT04/05, Tanjung Perak",//streetAddress
                                "addressLocality":"Jimbaran",//addressLocality
                                "postalCode":"56161"//postalCode
                                }
                            }                    
        }      
} 
</script>
```

From the structure data above,`baseSalary` expects type of `MonetaryAmount`, where the value is the amount of the salary, as follow:

```json
      "baseSalary":{
      "@type":"MonetaryAmount",
          "value":"100000",
          },
```

However, when the `baseSalary` has been added and verified, Google, again, gave me error in `currency` which I placed it inside `baseSalary`:

```json
      "baseSalary":{
      "@type":"MonetaryAmount",
          "value":"100000",
          "currency":"USD"
          },
```

[image: Google SDTT parses baseSalary correctly]

Done successfully.

Comment: How to write with Microdata?

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to @huykon225 question about microdata above, because I can't find that this question is answered in microdata context anywhere although the internet is full of corrected versions of json. Frustrated me, just took an hour or more to sort it...

Replace this in the original code:

```
<span itemprop="salaryCurrency">USD</span> <span itemprop="baseSalary">100000</span>
```

With this:

```
<div itemprop="baseSalary" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/MonetaryAmount">
<span itemprop="currency">USD</span>
<span itemprop="value">100000</span>
</div>
```